# How do I grab the AR1 estimate and its SE from the gls function in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I am attempting to get the lag one autocorrelation estimates from the gls function (package {nlme}) with its SE. This is being done on a non-stationary univariate time series. Here is the output:

```
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: y ~ year
  Data: tempdata 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  51.28921 54.37957 -21.64461

Correlation Structure: AR(1)
 Formula: ~1 
 Parameter estimate(s):
      Phi 
0.9699799 

Coefficients:
                 Value Std.Error    t-value p-value
(Intercept) -1.1952639  3.318268 -0.3602072  0.7234
year        -0.2055264  0.183759 -1.1184567  0.2799

 Correlation: 
        (Intr)
year    -0.36 

Standardized residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-0.12504485 -0.06476076  0.13948378  0.51581993  0.66030397 

Residual standard error: 3.473776 
Degrees of freedom: 18 total; 16 residual
```

The phi coefficient seemed promising since it was under the correlation structure in the output

```
Correlation Structure: AR(1)
 Formula: ~1 
 Parameter estimate(s):
      Phi 
0.9699799
```

but it regularly goes over one, which is not possible for correlation. Then there is the

```
Correlation: 
        (Intr)
Yearctr -0.36
```

but I was advised that this was likely not a correct estimate for the data (there were multiple test sites so this is just one of the unexpected estimates). Is there a function that outputs an AR1 estimate and its SE (other than arima)?

```
sample of autocorrelated data:
set.seed(29)
y = diffinv(rnorm(500))
x = 1:length(y)
gls(y~x, correlation=corAR1(form=~1))
```

Note: I am comparing the function arima() to gls() (or another method) to compare AR1 estimates and SE's. I am doing this under adviser request.